# Как внести изменения в файле Open XML который находится в памяти и сохранить изменения не используя диск?(C#)

Tags: c#, openxml

Задача эталонный файл xlsx загрузить в память, внести в него изменения и сохранить изменения в памяти(не на диске).

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("File.xlsx");
// Создаем массив байт для хранения фала в памяти
// +50000 на случай если изменения будут больше чем исходный файл, 
// вообще это можно так делать или я гоню?
byte[] newFile = new byte[f.Length+50000];
// Переносим файл с диска на память
File.WriteAllBytes("File.xlsx", newFile);
// Создаем поток из байтового массива что бы можно было использовать его в SpreadsheetDocument.Open
streamNewFile = new MemoryStream(newFile, true);
// Пытаемся открыть xlsx находящийся в памяти
SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(streamNewFile, true); // ошибка происходит тут
// что то делаем с таблицей
// закрываем таблицу
 document.Close();
// возвращаем массив байтов с сохраненной таблицей
return streamNewFile.ToArray();
```

Может я использую не тот подход? Посоветуйте что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем вам вообще поток в памяти? просто с диска нельзя файл открыть нормальными методами сразу?

Comment: Дело в том, что это приложение будет на сервере и к нему могут часто обращаться, я бы не хотел что бы были частые обращения к диску.

Answer (score 1):

По порядку.

`File.xlsx` - представляет из себя `zip` архив с набором данных необходимых для `Microsoft Excel`, по этому строка:

```
byte[] newFile = new byte[f.Length+50000];
```

В корне неверно. Сделав новый массив побольше - этим вы не создадите буфер для изменения файла. `newFile` - больше не является валидным zip-архивом

По-этому при попытке открыть `newFile` вы получаете ошибку с явным ответом:

> Файл содержит повреждённые данные

Почитав документацию к `SpreadsheetDocument` понял, что файл в памяти оставить не получится, т.к. класс не предоставляет методов для сохранения документа в поток. Поэтому самый верный вариант будет - это скопировать исходный вариант на диск и изменять его копию. Далее открыть изменённый файл и сохранить его в памяти.

Ответ, наверно, будет таким:

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("File.xlsx");

//Копируем файл в новый
FileInfo newFile = f.CopyTo("NewFile.xlsx");

//открываем файл и считываем из него данные
SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(newFile.Open(FileMode.Open), true);

//Производим манипуляции

//Вызов этого метода сохраняет изменения в файл и закрывает документ
document.Close();

using (var fs = newFile.Open(FileMode.Open))
{
    //Тут считываем файл и отдаём полученный массив байт куда нужно
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за решение! А скажите, можно ли как то избежать обращения к диску. что бы один раз прочитать исходный файл в память и работать с ним. Дело в том, что это приложение будет на сервере и к нему могут часто обращаться, я бы не хотел что бы были частые обращения к диску.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, избежать обращения к диску никак не получится. Можно попробовать только один раз считать `File.xlsx` в массив `byte[]` и работать с ним создавая новые файлы на диске (`File.WriteAllBytes("NewFile.xlsx", byte[])`) и редактируя их через `SpreadsheetDocument.Open("NewFile.xlsx", true)`.

Comment: Я использовал такое решение и все стало ок: var ms = new MemoryStream();
var originalStream = File.Open(...));
originalStream.CopyTo(ms);
var document =  SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true);
//Производим манипуляции
document.Close();
var blob = ms.ToArray();

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, Странно! В оф доке на msdn написано, что метод `Close()` должен закрывать и освобождать используемые ресурсы. По идее `MemoryStream` должен был быть закрыт. Но это хорошо, что вы смогли решить свою проблему

Answer (score 1):

Используя MemoryStream вместо второго файла можно решить этот вопрос:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();

var originalStream = File.Open(...));

originalStream.CopyTo(ms);

var document =  SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true);

...

document.Close();

var blob = ms.ToArray();
```